# Downloading Telegram videos

Tags: telegram, bulk-download, video-download

I never have used Telegram before, I just downloaded both in my phone and in my pc the Telegram app in order to subscribe to a private channel where I paid a subscription. I think that the model has made unavailable the possibility to download her videos because of piracy or maybe Im just ignorant. 1. If this girl made unavailable the download of her videos, Does exist a method for a nontechsavvy like me to download the telegram content that I paid? 2. Telegram does not allow this and Im just ignorant? if that is the case what should I do in order to download her content ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is [protected content](https://telegram.org/blog/protected-content-delete-by-date-and-more)

> **Protected Content in Groups and Channels**

> With this update, we're helping creators protect the content they publish on Telegram and ensure that it is available only for their intended audience.

> Group and Channel owners who want to keep their content members-only can restrict message forwarding from their chat, which also prevents screenshots and limits the ability to save media from posts.